# Where is the code behind Add button for Winform BindingNavigator Control?

Tags: winforms

There is code for save button, but I can't see any code behind the Add button though the button works ?

So what would it be as I want to create my own not from scratch ?

Thanks.

Comment: Only 4 persons have viewed the question ?

Comment: I'm not offering Bounty (don't know exactly what it is but let's do it :))

Comment: Leaving a comment so your replies indicator turns orange, my answer is updated to better respond to your question, instead of my mis-read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way the add button wires up, is to the underlying type or BindingSource. Based on the behavior I saw yesterday, if the underlying list was bound to a type that had an empty constructor it was enabled, if not, the button was disabled. So it should be

```
this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.AddNew();
this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.MoveLast();
```

if you have something where you don't want the default constructor use something like this:

```
this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.Add(new T(1));
this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.MoveLast();
```

The save code would be as such:

If you are using a strongly typed dataset the code would be like

```
DataSet.AcceptChanges();
```

or if using tableAdapters

```
var myTableAdapter=new DataSet1TableAdapters.assetTableAdapter();
myTableAdapter.Update(DataSet);
```

You may not be getting many views on a holiday/weekend.

Comment: sorry meant to say double clicking the save button, if you are looking for where to put your code. the rest applies to if you are trying to make a save button. Which depends on what technologies you are using to connect to the database.

Comment: I'm not asking about the save button but the add button :
Sure I did see the code behind the save button already but I can't see any behind the add button :)

Comment: Here's some additional information that may be helpful: http://briannoyes.net/CommentView,guid,64275c83-d7af-4a19-b4f7-593146ab415f.aspx

Comment: Or you can use this when saving (using tableAdapters):
this.Validate();
this.tbl_YourBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.YourDataSetName);

Answer (score 2):

If you are using strongly typed data source ( linke BindingSource ) to bind to BindingNavigator the Add button should work out of the box along with the other buttons like Move First,Next,Last,Previous, PoistionItem ( the textbox showing current record ).

To add your own handler for the Add button on
 bindingNavigator ( bindingNavigatorAddNewItem ), please follow the steps given below:
1. right click on add button and select properties from context menu.
2. In the properties window goto events tab. ( The one with symbol of lightning )
3. Double click on Click.
It will create an event handler in your code file.

If the Add button is disabled you can enable it by  selecting enable from context menu on Add button.